# First step of Kernel Ridge Regression?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, ridge-regression

I want to implement kernel ridge regression (KRR) using a polynomial kernel as a function that takes the training objects, training labels and test objects as arguments, and outputs the vector of predicted labels for test objects (in R).

The problem is this is not something I study so I am struggling to find a starting point for this algorithm. This is the guide I would like to follow: http://stat.wikia.com/wiki/Kernel_Ridge_Regression (unless somebody can recommend me a better one).

Suppose I have a data set like this, where the first 3 are training objects (Sales is the label) and the rest are test objects:

```
TV  Radio   Newspaper   Sales
230.1   37.8    69.2    22.1
44.5    39.3    45.1    10.4
17.2    45.9    69.3    9.3
151.5   41.3    58.5    18.5
180.8   10.8    58.4    12.9
8.7     48.9    75      7.2
```

Does anybody know if the guide is using a polynomial or radial kernel? I have my training objects, training labels and test objects. What is the first step I should take? How are BETA and LAMBDA calculated?

I have been looking into this for quite some time and can't find any tutorial that breaks it down into baby steps. Would REALLY appreciate any insight.

Comment: Please [merge](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts. [a](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/97625/blurub) and [b](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/97624/user97624)